# PHP Code inserts Blank Records in MySql database with _POST method

Tags: php, html, mysql, database, insert

PHP code is inserting blank records when inserting data in the database with the _POST Method, However when I use _GET everything works fine.

Thanks in Advace.

```
<?php
$con=mysqli_connect("localhost","root","*******","student");
// Check connection
if (mysqli_connect_errno())
  {
  echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
  }

$sql="INSERT INTO Student (textnames, fathername, mom, occu, homenum, paddress, offcontact, Course, District, State, pincode, emailid, dob, mobileno)
VALUES
('$_POST[textnames]','$_POST[fathername]','$_POST[mom]','$_POST[occu]','$_POST[homenum]','$_POST[paddress]','$_POST[offcontact]','$_POST[Course]','$_POST[District]','$_POST[State]','$_POST[pincode]','$_POST[emailid]','$_POST[dob]','$_POST[mobileno]')";

if (!mysqli_query($con,$sql))
  {
  die('Error: ' . mysqli_error($con));
  }
echo "Successfully Added Record";

mysqli_close($con);
?>
```

Any suggestions how to avoid this.....

Comment: Specify `method=POST` on your Form tag and retry with `$_POST`.

Comment: its there '<td><form name="form1" method="post" action="insert.php">'

Comment: Have you tried assigning the POST variables to your own named variables first, then insert those named variables?

Comment: I believe this has been answered here:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9617982/inserting-variable-or-post-value-into-mysql-table

Comment: aren't you meant to surround `{$_GET['textnames']}` with quotes, none of your `$_GET` keys have quotes eg `$_GET[textnames]`

Comment: GET WOrks Fine its the _POST method which ain't working let me update the questions sorry about that guys..

Comment: Off topic, but this query is terribly insecure.

Answer (score 0):

a good rule of thumb is checking PHP Variables availability with phpinfo (this is related to your web server configuration).

Try and add:

```
echo phpinfo();
exit;
```

just before your

```
 if (!mysqli_query($con,$sql))
```

Answer (score 0):

The reason is that you are most probably doing the post not same as get

```
'$_POST[textnames]'// is wrong
'$_POST["textnames"]'// is correct
```

and same with all others. You must have used quotes to get these values without quotes your index like `textnames` would be incorrect both for `GET` and `POST`

Answer (score 0):

try to initialise the $_POST to a local variable and use the query as follows

```
    <?php
$a=$_POST['textname'];
$b=$_POST['fathername'];
$c=$_POST['mom'];'
$d=$_POST['occu'];
$e=$_POST['homenum'];
$f=$_POST['paddress'];
$g=$_POST['offcontact'];
$i=$_POST['Course'];
$j=$_POST['District'];
$k=$_POST['State'];
$l=$_POST['pincode'];
$m=$_POST['emailid'];
$o=$_POST['dob'];
$p=$_POST['mobileno']
$con=mysqli_connect("localhost","root","*******","student");
// Check connection
if (mysqli_connect_errno())
  {
  echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
  }

$sql="INSERT INTO Student (textnames, fathername, mom, occu, homenum, paddress, offcontact, Course, District, State, pincode, emailid, dob, mobileno) VALUES('$a','$b','$c','$d','$e','$f','$g','$i','$j','$k','$l','$m','$o','$p')";

if (!mysqli_query($con,$sql))
  {
  die('Error: ' . mysqli_error($con));
  }
echo "Successfully Added Record";

mysqli_close($con);
?>
```

Comment: Dnt forget to add <form name="somename" method="POST" action="urphp.php">

Answer (score 0):

First check whether your form is sending value by

```
if(isset($_POST["submit"]))
     {
       Your insert query here

      }
 also in form try using following code
 <form methode = "POST" action = "">
 </form>
```

Comment: i have checked this it is working for me if you are not having submit button try with some different value in post e.g. if(isset($_POST["textnames"])) {} also try to insert values with double quotes eg. $_POST["tesxtnames"]

Answer (score 0):

It works with the _REQUEST i think it'll do

```
<?php
$con=mysqli_connect("localhost","root","********","student");
// Check connection
if (mysqli_connect_errno())
  {
  echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
  }

$sql="INSERT INTO Student (textnames, fathername, mom, occu, homenum, paddress, offcontact, Course, District, State, pincode, emailid, dob, mobileno)
VALUES
('$_REQUEST[textnames]','$_REQUEST[fathername]','$_REQUEST[mom]','$_REQUEST[occu]','$_REQUEST[homenum]','$_REQUEST[paddress]','$_REQUEST[offcontact]','$_REQUEST[Course]','$_REQUEST[District]','$_REQUEST[State]','$_REQUEST[pincode]','$_REQUEST[emailid]','$_REQUEST[dob]','$_REQUEST[mobileno]')";
if (!mysqli_query($con,$sql))
  {
  die('Error: ' . mysqli_error($con));
  }
echo "Successfully Added Record";

mysqli_close($con);
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can change your code like this. The point is you missed the single quotes when accessed the post variables.

```
<?php
$con=mysqli_connect("localhost","root","*******","student");
// Check connection
if (mysqli_connect_errno())
  {
  echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
  }

$sql="INSERT INTO Student (textnames, fathername, mom, occu, homenum, paddress, offcontact, Course, District, State, pincode, emailid, dob, mobileno)
VALUES
('".$_POST['textnames']."','".$_POST['fathername']."','".$_POST['mom']."','".$_POST['occu']."','".$_POST['homenum']."','".$_POST['paddress']."','".$_POST['offcontact']."','".$_POST['Course']."','".$_POST['District']."','".$_POST['State']."','".$_POST['pincode']."','".$_POST['emailid']."','".$_POST['dob']."','".$_POST['mobileno']."')";

if (!mysqli_query($con,$sql))
  {
  die('Error: ' . mysqli_error($con));
  }
echo "Successfully Added Record";

mysqli_close($con);

    }

}
?>
```